# How to check international filepath symbols on correctness?

Tags: c++, filepath, utf-32

In my c++ linux application I load a file with file list.
Every single line is a full path to some file (utf32) and can have international symbols.

Is there a way check these lines for character correctness? Maybe some library?
Need to avoid emoji or symbols like that.

These files are outside, so I cannot check each of them for availability.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what you need to do?

Comment: [Who said](https://imgur.com/I0mmPNk.png) filenames can't contain emojis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say in general "yes", but your question is very vague. If international characters are allowed, that opens up thousands of character (code points, in Unicode parliance) for use.

Filtering out some set is of course possible, but it's going to be tricky to define that set in a way that works for everyone.

I would recommend against it, just let the filenames be free, don't try to validate them.

Comment: I was in doubt of this solution, now I see - free filnames are normal. Thank you very much.